# SwiftSpinner not working on UIViewController.

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

Ok, so I am using this project: https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner

I downloaded the project and took the Swiftspinner.Swift file from the directory and added it to my project.

Now, When I add in a test like so:

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    SwiftSpinner.show("Test")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Nothings happens when I run it. no errors it just says build succeeded and then opens in the simulator. 
However, If I change the class delegation at the top to this:

```
class ViewController: UINavigationController {
```

I works, Can anyone fathom this out?

Comment: Try moving the call to `viewDidAppear(_:)`

Comment: Already tried that, nothing.

Comment: Ah, actually, I tried that but I had left it also in the viewDidLoad. When I took it out of the viewdidload also it worked. - do you want to add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to `viewDidAppear(_:)`.

The problem is that ViewController is more than likely the initial view that is created when you created the project. `viewDidLoad()` is called when `.view` is called on your controller. Since this is the initial view controller it has not yet been added to the key window. As a result the spinner adds itself to the key window then ViewController is added to key window covering up the spinner. If you used the view hierarchy debugger you will be able to see this happen. Once the root view is set this would no longer be an issue but it is still best practice to modify the UI after the view has appeared.

Comment: Really appreciated your help dude. Thanks.